# OAuth 2 authentication without client registration.(Client ID)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to authenticate a service using OAuth 2.0 without the Client ID?

Answer (score 1):

**NO!**

No matter which authentication flow you use, you must register an application. When you request an access token, the **client id** is required!

In nearly all OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect flows, there are four parties involved in the exchange:

[image]

See:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably imitate the login flow at your end with the required parameters. You could a take Fiddler Traces with HTTPS decoded to understand the flow.

[image]

In the response, I could see the Bearer token.

[image]

Which can be used in the subsequent calls.

Again this is not a suitable or a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not possible*, we can see that in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
Parameter   Condition   Description
------------------------------------
client_id   Required    The Application (client) ID that the Azure portal – App 
                        registrations experience assigned to your app.
```

The client id is always required when you request an access token!